# Create a list of variables in stylus

Tags: stylus

Suppose I have color variable:

```
golden: rgb(212, 196, 112)
```

Is there a way I could generate variables

```
golden-01 = golden + 1%
golden-02 = golden + 2%
golden-03 = golden + 3%
golden-04 = golden + 4%
golden-05 = golden + 5%
// etc....
```

using one of the stylus iterations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `for` loop and `define` built-in function:

```
golden = rgb(212, 196, 112)

for i in 1..5
  define('golden-0' + i, golden + (i)%)

body
  color: golden-01 // #d4c571
```